# Send File Via Ftp Using VB.Net In .Net 2003

Tags: vb.net, ftp

I want to send the file via FTP on server using vb.net(Vs 2003,framework 1.1) is throwing an exception

> AN EXCEPTION OCCURED DURING THE WEBCLIENT REQUEST

The same code is working fine in .Net 2008. I have no Idea why its throwing the exception.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Text
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Net.WebRequest
Imports System.Net.WebClient
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO


If (Directory.Exists(directoryPath)) Then
    arrFileList = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath) '''Getting All files 
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Directory not Exist")
End If

    For i As Integer = 0 To i < arrFileList.Length - 1

            Try
                Dim fileName As String = arrFileList.GetValue(i)
                Dim toUpload As New FileInfo(fileName)
                Dim client As New WebClient

                Dim nc As New NetworkCredential("xxxx", "xxxx") 

                Dim addy As Uri
                addy = New Uri("ftp://1xx.xx.xxx.xxx/HYPOSII_FTP/Test/" & toUpload.Name.ToString())               


                client.Credentials = nc
                Dim arrReturn As Byte() = client.UploadFile(addy.ToString(), fileName) //This Line Throwing error
                MessageBox.Show("File Uploaded Sucessfully")
                FLAG = True                
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            End Try
        Next
```

Comment: Your `For` loop should read `For i As Integer = 0 To arrFileList.Length - 1`; having the `i <` in there will allow the loop to run at most once.

Comment: Thanks for reply David....My loop is working fine but at the time of uploading it's  throwing the exception . You can check that line where i mention the comment also.

Comment: Sorry - I didn't mean that changing the `For` loop would solve the uploading problem. It's just a syntactical thing that will not allow the loop to run all the way through.

Comment: Since .NET 1.1 doesn't have an FTP client built into the framework, it's relying on the OS to do the transfer, and just sort of reporting if the underlying Windows APIs return an error code. For .NET 1.1 FTP applications, we've had good success with edtFTPnet (http://enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpnet/overview.html).

Comment: Thanks for reply David.... I gone through the framework of 1.1 and found that It's not supporting the FTP client or Webclient request from windows application....Thanks for edtFTPnet suggestion but my Client is not ready to invest... anyhow i got the another way to solve this issue..Now i am achieving the goal by using Batch File. David Thanks again for you support....Thank you very much.

Comment: Sure thing. For what it's worth, that link is to a free version of the FTP library. There is a pro version as well - that's the one to use if you need secure FTP support.